# WSL resolver need to resolve both internally and externally

Tags: dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was unable to ping internal hosts.
I created an /etc/resolv.conf file in the form

```
nameserver internal
nameserver internal
search internal.mycomp.com mycomp.com
```

This **worked** perfectly for resolving *internal* host names.
However, ping www.google.com or ping www.ubuntu.com would now fail.
So, *sudo apt-get* would also fail.

I added opendns to resolv.conf

```
nameserver opendns
nameserver internal
nameserver internal
search internal.mycomp.com mycomp.com
```

Now ping www.ubuntu.com works, but internal resolution fails.
It would be nice to have both internal and external DNS working simultaneously.